# saml2Login method cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I followed [Spring Security SAML2 Using G Suite as Idp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419768/spring-security-saml2-using-g-suite-as-idp)
Cannot resolve method 'saml2login' in 'Http Security'
I am getting this error
some body plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
I am using spring boot 2.1.x version in my project. On changing it to 4.2.1, issue is solved.